# Dúvidas sobre o item do menu "Sem resposta" do StackOverflow

Tags: suporte, perguntas-sem-resposta

Porque o StackOverflow indica que algumas "perguntas sem resposta" não tem resposta quando na verdade logo abaixo da pergunta existem pelo menos uma resposta ou mais?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade o espaço da aba não permite a descrição total do que ela significa, portanto, logo abaixo tem um texto dissertando mais sobre quais tipos de perguntas são filtradas nela:

Imagem:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Descrição:

> perguntas sem resposta aceita nem com voto a favor
>   em suas tags

Ou seja, pode parecer incoerente, mas essa aba também mostra perguntas que possuem respostas, desde que essas respostas aparentemente não tenham sido úteis nem para o autor da pergunta nem para a comunidade.

Comment: Obrigado Math Poderia me explicar melhor ?

Comment: Sim, claro. Quis dizer que ele filtra "perguntas sem resposta aceita nem com voto a favor em suas tags", logo, pode a pergunta pode até ter uma ou mais respostas, mas elas não tem voto a favor nem aceite

Comment: Ok! Agora está claro!! Então aquelas respostas que eu vejo não foram aceitas como  respostas ideais!!